# Can lists and carousels from the Actions SDK be purely informational?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm creating an action that would like to use the carousel and list response types (on supported surfaces) to display information (title & description) but don't really have a need for them to be clicked. However, this is enabled by default. Is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: As per my knowledge, I think there is no way to do that right now. It will be nice feature to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, Lists and Carousels are just for allowing a user to select from a list of items.

Comment: Do you have any documentation or are you on the team or something to confirm this answer? Then, I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Apologies for not providing more details!It's implied in the names (ListSelector and CarouselSelector) and described in the high level descriptions: "The single-select list presents the user with a vertical list of multiple items and allows the user to select a single one." and "The carousel scrolls horizontally and allows for selecting one item."

Comment: Makes sense... I was just hoping there was a way to have it function as just a read only display element. Hopefully in a future version... Thanks!